# Terraform cloud config dynamic workspace name

Tags: terraform, devops, hashicorp

I'm building CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions and Terraform. I have a main.tf file like below, which I'm calling from GitHub action for multiple environments. I'm using https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform to interact with Terraform in GitHub actions. I have MyService component and I'm deploying to DEV, UAT and PROD environments. I would like to reuse main.tf for all of the environments and dynamically set workspace name like so: MyService-DEV, MyService-UAT, MyService-PROD. Usage of variables is not allowed in the terraform/cloud block. I'm using HashiCorp cloud to store state.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }

  cloud {
    organization = "tf-organization"
    workspaces {
      name = "MyService-${env.envname}" #<==not allowed to use variables
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

I finally managed to get this up and running with helpful comments. Here are my findings:

- TF_WORKSPACE needs to be defined upfront like: service-dev
- I didn't get tags to work the way I want when running in automation. If I define a tag in cloud.workspaces.tags as 'service' then there is no way to set a second tag like 'dev' dynamically. Both of the tags are needed to during init ['service', 'dev'] in order for TF to select workspace service-dev automatically.
- I ended up using tfe provider in order to set up workspaces(with tags) automatically. In the end I still needed to set TF_WORKSPACE=service-dev

Comment: "I would like to reuse main.tf for all of the environments" this is default behavior. "dynamically set workspace name" TF Cloud workspace or CLI workspace? Also, could you please add your specific question?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I want main.tf to be aware of environment(dev, uat, prod) and service name (API1, Web1) so that inside main.tf I can use TF cloud block and say that cloud.workspaces.name = $service_name-$environment. After running all this I would expect to see 6 workspaces in TF cloud: API1-dev, Web1-dev, API1-uat, Web1-uat, Api1-prod, Web1-prod. Question is how to define and use dynamic settings in cloud block?

Comment: @Fuczak How did you end up initializing the cloud workspaces block?

Comment: @DavidBrown, I steered it using ENV variables in my Github actions. Like this: env:
  TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
  TF_WORKSPACE: "${{inputs.service}}-${{inputs.environment}}". In the cloud block I have one tag defined just so that TF does not complain (tags or name must be defined)

Comment: @Fuczak So you had to add a dummy tag to each workspace then? 

I'm considering just generating the terraform cloud block in a bash script with a hard coded workspace name before running terraform init.

Comment: @DavidBrown, I have an organization tag 'orgname' for all workspaces (also other tags like service and environment). Then I only use this one in my main.tf in the cloud block configuration. TF does not complain and anyway uses TF_WORKSPACE during init. Works well for me, no need to generate this block on the fly. It feels a bit like workaround but I didn't get any clear information how to do this by the book. This is pretty basic scenario for any reasonable setup.

Comment: The use of TF_WORKSPACE works only if you already have an existing Terraform Cloud workspace, doesn't it? I want to create workspaces dynamically in Terraform Cloud even when one doesn't exist already but init doesn't work if no workspace exists. I cannot run workspace new before because I didn't run init.

Comment: However using sed to replace dynamically set the name in terraform.cloud.workspaces.name and running init works to create a new workspace.

Comment: @JonasPauthier I ended up with a separate repo just to manage all Terraform related configuration (mainly workspaces). So managing Terraform Cloud using Terraform. Then the workspace is already there when initializing. It was a more convenient option for me as it does not involve messing with files. But I'm really scratching my head trying to understand why is this so cumbersome to configure in Terraform. This is a basic scenario in my opinion.

Comment: Yes I agree also. It seems at some point it messed up between the CLI workspace concept and the Terraform Cloud workspace concept. Perhaps I don't understand the idiomatic way of using it.

Comment: @Fuczak thanks for sharing how you were able to get this working. Would you be willing to share an example?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to refer to `terraform.workspace` as part of the `workspaces` block inside a `cloud` block, because that block defines which remote workspaces Terraform will use and therefore dictates what final value `terraform.workspace` will have in the rest of your configuration.

To declare that your Terraform configuration belongs to more than one workspace in Terraform Cloud, you can assign each of those workspaces the tag "MyService" and then use the `tags` argument instead of the `name` argument:

```
  cloud {
    organization = "tf-organization"
    workspaces {
      tags = ["MyService"]
    }
  }
```

If you assign that tag to hypothetical `MyService-dev` and `MyService-prod` workspaces in Terraform Cloud and then initialize with the configuration above, Terraform will present those two workspaces for selection using the `terraform workspace` commands when working in this directory.

`terraform.workspace` will then appear as either `MyService-dev` or `MyService-prod`, depending on which one you have selected.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the terraform.workspace - I missused it in my example. What I'm trying to achieve is to use cloud as a storage for state. Then I have a single file main.tf. From GitHub Actions I want to run job deploy.yml. I will pass variable to deploy.yml, say component_env=my_service-dev. Then from deploy.yml I want to run terraform init and pass this variable to main.tf define the TF Cloud workspace name in the cloud block. Similar to this: terraform init -backend-config=workspaces=[{name = "my_service-dev"}] https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21830

Comment: Otherwise, how do I achieve main.tf reusability (dev, uat, prod) if I always need to hardcode workspace name (or tags)?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing here, any luck @Fuczak